# How to order NSMutableArray with NSMutableArray inside

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I need so sort an array with an array inside, something like this:

```
 NSMutableArray * array_example = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 [array_example addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            string_1,
                            string_2,
                            string_3,
                            nil]
 ];
```

how can i order this array by the field "string_1" of the array???
any idea how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Watch out for the missing pointer for array_example, and the extra comma in the arrayWithObjects declaration, please refer to my answer below. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 4 and later, this is easily done using a [comparator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW6) block:

```
[array_example sortUsingComparator:^(NSArray *o1, NSArray *o2) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)[[o1 objectAtIndex:0] compare:[o2 objectAtIndex:0]];
}];
```

If you're interested in how blocks work, you can have a look at Apple's [Short Practical Guide to Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html).

If you wish to support iOS 3.x, you'd have to use a custom comparison function:

```
NSComparisonResult compareArrayFirstElement(NSArray *o1, NSArray *o2) {
    return [[o1 objectAtIndex:0] compare:[o2 objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

and then use:

```
[array_example sortUsingFunction:compareArrayFirstElement context:nil];
```

Comment: for your first example i need to do that block for each item of the array_example like: for(int i=0; i<[array_example count]; i++){...} i don t understand what will be the array "o1" and o2"

Comment: No you just have to use the code as it is written. I've added a link to Apple docs if you want more understanding of blocks. NSMutableArray reference doc can help you too.

Comment: Use `[[o2 objectAtIndex:0] compare:[o1 objectAtIndex:0]]` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array objects and call sortedArrayUsingSelector on each sub array, then replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject to inject back into the original array

```
    NSMutableArray * array_example = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [array_example addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"z",
                            @"a",
                            @"ddd",
                            nil]
    ];
    [array_example addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"g",
                            @"a",
                            @"p",
                            nil]
    ];
    NSLog(@"Original Array: %@", array_example);

    for(int i = 0; i < [array_example  count] ; i++){
        [array_example replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[array_example objectAtIndex:i] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
        // order sub array
    }
    NSLog(@"Sorted Array: %@", array_example);
```